# RabbitMQ SpringBoot migration - Error creating bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, java-17

I'm migrating a small java 8 Spring-Boot 2.1.0 project to Java 17 with Spring-Boot 2.6.3
The project uses RabbitMQ and is basically a serializer-deserializer.
The problem I'm encountering is that I cannot run the application because it fails to initialize this bean:

```
@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow fromDocToLDocFlow(AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(DOCUMENT_ROUTE)
                .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate).routingKey(documentBinding).exchangeName(documentExchange))
                .get();
    }
```

And the exception I get is this:

```
 Error creating bean with name 'fromDocToLDocFlow.amqp:outbound-channel-adapter#0' defined in class path resource [publisher/config/IntegrationFlowConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; 
nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expecting non-static method 'java.lang.Object org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.extractTypeIfPossible(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class)'... 14 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Expecting non-static method 'java.lang.Object org.springframework.integration.context.IntegrationObjectSupport.extractTypeIfPossible(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class)'
        at org.springframework.integration.amqp.outbound.AbstractAmqpOutboundEndpoint.doInit(AbstractAmqpOutboundEndpoint.java:409) ~[spring-integration-amqp-5.1.0.RELEASE.jar:5.1.0.RELEASE]
            ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Here is my gradle configuration:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.6.3'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.group'
sourceCompatibility = 17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-integration')
    implementation("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-feed:5.1.0.RELEASE")
    implementation("org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-amqp:5.1.0.RELEASE")

    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.1")
    implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0")

    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.22'
    testImplementation("junit:junit")
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation('commons-io:commons-io:2.11.0')
}
```

Compiled dependencies:

```
Gradle: org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.22
Gradle: org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:2.4.22
Gradle: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.6.32
Gradle: org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:1.3.1
```

Comment: Remove the version from the `org.springframework.integration` dependencies. You are using incompatible versions.

Comment: Thank you very much @M. Deinum I didn't notice that!